# call a method of a module from another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have defined a class `user_controller` where it calls a method `start_mail` from a module present in lib (`lib/mail_start.rb`). Within the same class, `User`,
I am calling a method `check_mail` present in `mail_check` module defined in lib - `lib/process/mail_check.rb`.

Problem is from  `check_mail` (method present in a module in lib file), I have to start mail so I have to call `start_mail` (method present in another module in same lib file).  To include `mail_start.rb` in module `mail_check.rb`, I have used  `include MailStart` and `require 'lib/mail_start'` in   module `MailCheck`.

But I am getting error as  `undefine method in module MailCheck`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define check_mail in helpers/mail_check and then include MailCheck in user_controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ths solution which I'm giving to you is what my assumption.
    **user_controller.rb**

```
require 'mail_start'  # You need to re-write your code

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  p include MailCheck
  def index
  end
end
```

And Module would be `lib/mail_start.rb`

```
module MailCheck
  def check_mail
    p "calls"
  end
end
```

Should work for you as well !!!

Answer (score 0):

Auto load the path of parent directory of the module in `config/application.rb`

Try this

```
module YourAppNAme
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/process)
  end
end
```

Then `include` it in the `user_controller`

```
include MailCheck
```

I hope this would be helpful.